# Remove Spacing Between Drop Down Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

One final question with my CSS drop down box!

I can not seem to remove the space in between the links "Link 1", "Link 2" and "Link 3". Under the Products drop down.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#cssdropdown li.headlink ul li { padding:0; margin:0; }

Worked in Firefox 3.5

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with the margin you have set

```
#header li {
display:inline;
float:left;
list-style-image:none;
margin:30px 15px 0;  <-- This line 
}
```

You will find [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to be an invaluable tool in troubleshooting CSS as you can enable, disable, and modify CSS elements in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.headlink>ul>li{ margin: 5px 0; }
```

Edit: resetting the padding like DaClown does is unnecessary.